# ASP.Net - constructing a Dataset from a single Grid Row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I`m making an ASP.Net site. One of the pages contains a GridView of users which I want to display. Each row represends a user.

When a `Search` button is clicked, I want to find a specific user-row by their name (which I already implemented); Then, I want to pass to the cache a dataset which contains only that one row (which will then be updated, and displayed in the gridView).

So I made this:

```
protected void Search_Click(object 
        sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow myRow = findRow(UsersView, userSearched.Text, 0);
        if (myRow==null)//Pretty much a must-have since it's QD built.
        {
            ResponseLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            ResponseLabel.Text = "User not found.";
            return;
        }
        ResponseLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        ResponseLabel.Text = "There you go.";
        DataTable container = new DataTable(); // the problem starts here
        DataRow convertedForTable = container.NewRow();
        for (int i = 0; i < myRow.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            convertedForTable.ItemArray[i] = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
        }

        Cache["Users"] = container;
        UpdateSource(); // puts a dataset in the gridView.
    }
```

I get an `IndexOutOfBounds` in the datarow itemArray. - and that's after many different attempts to do this in many different ways.  I wonder how can I make this work, or alternativley if there's a better solution.

Comment: Shouldn't you be defining columns for the new DataTable before accessing ItemArray?

Comment: There are some problems with your code, did you solve ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problem with your code

First if you run it you will get this error :

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

so you can make a row array object by your `Cells.Count` then set cells item text to the array items after that you can set it to `ItemArray` like this:

```
DataTable container = new DataTable(); 
DataRow convertedForTable = container.NewRow();
object[] rowArray = new object[myRow.Cells.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < myRow.Cells.Count; i++)
     {
            rowArray[i] = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
     }
convertedForTable.ItemArray = rowArray;
```

Second but by running the above code you will also get this error :

> Input array is longer than the number of columns in this table.

you know why because the number of your `container` Data Table cells must be equal to `myRow` cells in the other word the `containar` does not have any column!

so I suppose `myRow` have there columns something like below code:

```
DataTable container= new DataTable();
container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("UserName", typeof(string)));
container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
container.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Family", typeof(string)));
DataRow convertedForTable = container.NewRow();
object[] rowArray = new object[myRow.Cells.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < myRow.Cells.Count; i++)
       rowArray[i] = myRow.Cells[i].Text;
convertedForTable.ItemArray = rowArray;
container.Rows.Add(convertedForTable);
```

The above code works fine, 
to resolve your problem take a look at [DataRow and ItemArray](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray(v=vs.110).aspx)
and this [Link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/annathurai/data-cache-in-Asp-Net/) and [ASP.Net Caching Techniques and Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478965.aspx) can be useful for DataTable caching.

Hope this will help.